# Checking external app version name in android

Tags: android

I would like to know how to read installed apk version.
For example, from my app i would like to know what version of Skype is installed on my phone.

To Read my app version i use:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Of course with try/catch surrounded.

Comment: For android 11, you need to define specific **package** in android manifest or if your app has need to get All packages, then you would need to add `android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission. But with this permission going to play store, you need to make sure that your app complies the policy: [https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility#all-apps]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to figure out what is the right package name of the skype installed on your device.

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.skype.android", 0);

//getVersionCode is Deprecated, instead use getLongVersionCode().
long verCode = pinfo.getLongVersionCode();
//getVersionName is Deprecated, instead use versionName
String verName = pinfo.versionName;
```

You can get all packages and find out name with the following method call:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Comment: I did not see methods like pinfo.getVersionCode() or pinfo.getVersionName(). Please see my answer at the bottom for working code.

Comment: @Mobistry to see that you should look back into 2012.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( "com.myapp", 0 );
String verName = pinfo.versionName;
int verCode = pinfo.versionCode;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able do this using something like this:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

PackageInfo mypackage = <get required app from the list>;

String versionName = mypackage.versionName;
int versionCode = mypackage.versionCode;
```

Have a look at [PackageInfo class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html).