# Samsung Experience version

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I'm writing an android application and i need to detect what version of Samsung Experience the device is running to do a special check. Galaxy S8 with android 7.0 allows the navigation bar to be on the left. And from my understanding only android 7.1 allows that. My application apply margins based on android version and I need to check if the version is 7 and we are running Samsung Experience 8.1.

Here you can find an example of About phone.

Another posibility is detect the position of the navigation bar on the screen (right or left). I could not find a way to do it.

thanks in advance.

I tried reading with Build.MODEL, Build.TAGS, Build.MANUFACTURER.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Checking external app version name in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988958/checking-external-app-version-name-in-android)

I don't have a Samsung Galaxy S8 available at the moment, but I think you can check the version of packages **com.sec.android.app.launcher** or **com.samsung.android.mobileservice**.